# How search triple elements (key_value pair Dictionary) by one of them - IEnumerable error

Tags: c#, dictionary

Here is my code:

```
public class PairedKeys
{
    public byte Key_1 { get; set; }
    public byte Key_2 { get; set; }

    public PairedKeys(byte key1, byte key2)
    {
        Key_1 = key1;
        Key_2 = key2;
    }
}

public static class My_Class
{
    static Dictionary<PairedKeys, char> CharactersMapper = new Dictionary<PairedKeys, char>()
    {
        { new PairedKeys(128, 48), 'a' },
        { new PairedKeys(129, 49), 'b' }
    }
}
```

How can I get value of `CharactersMapper` by searching `Key_2` as character?

Here's my attempt:

```
byte b = 48;
char ch = CharactersMapper.Where(d => d.Key.Key_2 == b);
```

and error :

> `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<PairedKeys,char>>'`

Comment: Just a note about `PairedKeys`: this is the case, when `struct` is preferable, than `class`.

Comment: you are not using indexer in this code.there are some other errors but the actual error should be in somewhere else

Comment: The `Where()` clause returns an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<PairedKey, char>>`, not a single `char` value.

Comment: how can i get that char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you got that precise error message. The problem is that the Where clause returns a KeyValuePair, not a char. The following unit test passes and demonstrates the solution (first you must change the CharactersMapper static variable to public):

```
[TestMethod]
public void Testing()
{
    byte b = 48;
    var item = My_Class.CharactersMapper
                       .Where(d => d.Key.Key_2 == b)
                       .FirstOrDefault();

    Assert.IsNotNull(item, "not found");

    char ch = item.Value;
    Assert.AreEqual('a', ch, "wrong value found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
byte b = 48;
char ch = My_Class.CharactersMapper.First(d => d.Key.Key_2 == b).Value;
```

You will still want some error handling for the case when the key doesn't exist.